# Spring Boot 3.0 package javax.validation does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation, jakarta-migration

I'm trying to use a method parameter [validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.7/reference/htmlsingle/#io.validation) feature supported by Bean Validation 1.1. For instance, the [following method](https://bitbucket.org/borisredkin/totp-authenticator/src/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/totpauthenticator/web/WebController.java#lines-55:63) triggers the validation of the first parameter, making sure it's valid:

```java
public String generateOtp(@Valid TotpAuthenticatorForm form, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

When I build a **Spring Boot 2.7.7** project it's fine, but building a **Spring Boot 3.0.1** project fails with a compilation error:

```
package javax.validation does not exist
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [release-notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes), Spring Boot 3.0 has migrated from Java EE to Jakarta EE APIs for all dependencies, including:

```
Jakarta Validation 3.0
```

- Spring Boot 2.7 - Jakarta Bean Validation 2.0
- Spring Boot 3.0 - Jakarta Bean Validation 3.0

You can fix the issue by using [Jakarta Bean Validation 3.0](https://beanvalidation.org/3.0/). Simply update import statements:

```java
javax.validation
->
jakarta.validation
```

Comment: It's work mentioning you need to include the following dependency, if you haven't yet:
`<dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId><version>8.0.0.Final</version></dependency>`

Comment: @dbaltor, we don't need to include it. Instead, we should use the `spring-boot-starter-validation` starter for using Java Bean Validation with Hibernate Validator in a Spring Boot project. See the [pom.xml](https://bitbucket.org/borisredkin/totp-authenticator/src/master/pom.xml#lines-46:49) for the example.

Comment: You're right @Boris. I knew about that with SB 2.x but that wasn't working with my current SB 3 project. I rebuilt everything with `mvn clean package` from the command line and it worked. I guess Intellij tripped down on this one.
Thanks!

Comment: I tried all the solution you proposed but nothing seems to work in my case. I am using jakarta packages and I am keeping doing mvn clean package and mvn clean install and rerun my app in intellij but validation is simply not working at all.

Comment: @FrancescoDassisis let's discuss it [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254399/room-for-boris-and-francesco-dassisis).

Comment: After adding the annotation @NotBlank in my REST API, using the library spring-boot-starter-validation version 3.1.0 my project stopped working giving a conflict between the Java version we use in our environment (JDK 8) and the version that the hibernate-validation library (inherited) is built (JDK 11).

Comment: @FelipeCaparelli, please read the release notes linked in my answer - "Spring Boot 3.0 requires Java 17 as a minimum version. If you are currently using Java 8 or Java 11, you’ll need to upgrade your JDK before you can develop Spring Boot 3.0 applications."